# CPU temp at 105° C (bad readings)

Tags: cpu, bios, fan, cooling, temperature

When I start my PC (Gigabyte H77M-D3H + i5 3570k) every temperature monitoring app I use says it's running on 50-60. When I start playing a game, it raises up to 100, but it never goes above 105.

I know the readings are wrong since the heat sink is cool, and the processor works just fine.

I've cleaned the fan, reattached it with new thermo past, made sure it really stands strong in the spot, no changes whatsoever. Also I've updated the BIOS to the newest one.

I've tried many different apps (AIDE64, Realtemp, CPU fan, etc.), all show the same. When I boot up BIOS shows CPU temp is about 59.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Which sensor, exactly, shows that temperature?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. It says CPU and for each CPU core the temp is as described. Mother board temp is always in the range of 27-35 °C.

Comment: Do you notice a decrease in performance as the temperature start to go higher? You wouldn't be able to feel it on the cooler. Does every core show up with 105°C?

Comment: No, no decrease in performance. I am certain that the real temp is nowhere near 105. Why would it stop on 105 even? Why not 106? 110? But it doesn't happen never.

Haven't seen every core at 105, but usually they are in the range of 100, and one core would be 105.

Comment: 105 sounds like a TJmax temp, so the processor would throttle once it reaches 105, attempting to not go over that. Despite your assurance that your CPU isn't that hot, it sounds to me like maybe your heatsink isn't making a good contact, and the cpu really is that hot! Especially if it corrosponds to load increase

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is wrong. **It is not unheard of for CPUs to reach such a high temperature**.

Also just because the CPU is reaching 100 it does not mean that the heat-sink will reach the same temperature.

One thing I would check, especially if the PC is a few years old is that it does not need to have Thermal Paste reapplied. Thermal Paste can sometimes dry up making the heat-sink ineffective at its designed purpose.

Comment: especially if the heatsink is making bad contact, the heastsink will be cool, while the processor is burning up. Also yes, TJmax for my CPU is 105 degrees

Comment: I've reapplied thermal paste. Also, as I've said, there's no decrease in performance, tests show the processor is doing fine.